# Magento 2 : Custom Dynamic Option with Fileuploader Fields in UI_Component

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, dynamic-rows, file-uploader

T have Work on Dynamic Option that contain file-upload field and i want to save dynamic option with file in magento 2.

[image]

Here we can see Option with Dynamic Option that contain file field.

What the use of

```
$uploaderFactory->addValidateCallback('custom_image_upload',$imageAdapter,'validateUploadFile');
```

Comment: what issue exactly you are facing ? Need to implement Dynamic Option ??

Comment: 'each option with image' i want to save image in option's array

Answer (score 1):

are your images uploaded well ? If it's the case, this is how you can save images in your database :
When you are saving you should call something like this : `$data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();` Just debug `$data`.
Normally you will see an array with all data you need from your form.
Just get the field name of your upload file field, pass it to your model and save :)

Hope it helps